# iPhone not recognized by MacBook 12"

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, usb, power

I want to connect an iPhone 6 to my 2016 12" MacBook.

I have a USB-C to USB-A adapter. If I connect the iPhone, macOS shows a warning (translated): `USB device requires power` (Note: It just says **power**, not **more power**). Original text is (German): `USB Zubehör benötigt Strom`. The iPhone is neither recognized by iTunes, nor does it charge.

The MacBook was connected to power supply via: MacBook USB-C to USB-A to USB-C MacBook power pack to power outlet. (My USB-C to USB-A Adapter has 2 USB-A outputs, so basically one output goes to iPhone, one to power supply).

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Too many adaptors, one of which is either faulty or not designed to do what you want. Connect just the USBC > Lightning cable to the Mac. Does it charge and can it be seen by iTunes?

Comment: Actually it´s just one adapter: The USB-C - USB-A, which really might be faulty. I dont have a lighting-USB-C cable.

Comment: Ah. You use a USBA > Lightning cable. Got it. Amazon (US) has a [USBC <> Lightning cable](https://www.amazon.com/Lightning-Charging-MCDODO-Delivery-lightning/dp/B078HX89Z7) for US$14.00. Apple's cable is  US$30. Perhaps it will be a worthwhile purchase.

Comment: thanks, t must be really the adapter then which causes the problem.